# winforms c# playing a youtube video I get a "restricted from playback on certain sites" error

Tags: c#, winforms, youtube

I've tried using WebBrowser and now trying with the Shockwave Flash tools and I can't seem to make it work with either one.  Using the webbrowser all I did was:

```
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value + "?autohide=0&autoplay=1&fs=0&rel=0");
```

also:

```
const string page = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>{0}</body></html>";
webBrowser1.DocumentText = string.Format(page, "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value + "?autohide=0&autoplay=1&fs=0&rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>");
```

ps. dataGridView1 is a grid of videos I have that the user can double click to watch.

and for the shockwave all I did was:

```
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value + "?autohide=0&autoplay=1&fs=0&rel=0";
```

and in all three methods I get the same error. help?

Comment: I can watch the video just fine in IE, Firefox, Chrome so it's not a country restriction.  And following that link, it's the same problem but I'm not coding for mobile it's a desktop application.  I wonder if there's some way of putting a domain to the webbrowser so it embeds correctly?

Comment: Why dont you try `Geckofx` browser instead of IE , [https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-22.0/downloads]